# Upgraded my Ubuntu server from Gutsy to Hardy and my Wordpress install got corrupted, help?

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress

Upgraded my Ubuntu server from Gutsy to Hardy and my Wordpress install got corrupted.  The front page and admin interface work, but all of the permalinks to individual blog posts are broken.  Have about 150+ blog posts, what is the best workaround?

Thinking of:
1) Creating a brand new Wordpress install and copying over one by one all of the blog posts via wp-admin by hand.  How could I port over permalinks and comments?

2) Is there a way to recover the data?  Fix the permalinks?

3) I didn't have WP backups on before.  Is it worth backing up Wordpress now and trying to port that backup to a fresh install?

If I turn off "pretty permalinks" and just use the standard :?p=123 format then the posts work, only the non-default permalinks are broken.  Does that point to a configuration problem with the web server setup instead of a corrupted database?  How can I tell if nginx is routing a request to wordpress correctly?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Serves you right for using WP in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the permalinks are broken then that sounds more like a WP issue then a corrupted upgrade issue. Do you have the ability to roll back the upgrade (i.e. backups)? Do you know if that actual database was corrupted? Those would be things I would check.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The problem was I was using nginx and the new version of nginx didn't work with Wordpress.  I had to install the "nginx" plugin for wordpress and it fixed the problem!  The widows and orphans will rejoice!  I'll actually also have to start donating money to widows and orphans!  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Mike: No problem. Just stop using WP! :)